# Mysql database syncing on will

Tags: php, mysql, replication, database-replication

We are using amazon rds for our ecommerce site. we are inserting/updating our products by using cron automation. We have around more than 5 millions of products. Whenever the automation starts the site goes to maintenance mode.Automation will take 6-7 hour to complete. So, we are planning to do achieve this in following way.

1. Use two separate databases, one is for automation (DB1) and other one is for site (DB2).
2. If admin or sales team add or update any products in admin panel, this data should update in DB1. We need something like real time syncing or we need to sync DB1 with DB2 at start of the automation.
3. After completing automation, a trigger or something like that will call. This will sync DB1 with DB2.

Thus both the DB1 and DB2 will be same. The methods like master slave replications is not feasible i think.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What are your reasons for thinking that master slave replication isn't feasible in your case?

Comment: I need to read and write in both the db's.It may cause some conflict i guess. Also i need some sort of event to sync the dbs at the end of the automation.

Comment: I see. This is one area you may be able to apply the use of a lambda function. You may trigger an SNS after completing automation and have your lambda trigger to run a sync command to manually manage the data replication.